# Convergence of summable sequences

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits, contest-math

If $(a_n)$ is a sequence such that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_1^4+a_2^4+\dots+a_n^4}{n}=0.$$

How do I show that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{a_1+a_2+\dots+a_n}{n}=0$?

Comment: Use Cauchy-Scwartz inequality.

Comment: Pls. Can you further explain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since:
$$\left|\sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k\right|\leq \sqrt{n}\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k^2}\leq n^{\frac{3}{4}}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k^4\right)^{\frac{1}{4}}$$
by applying the Cauchy-Schwarz' inequality twice (or the Holder's inequality once), we have:
$$\frac{1}{n}\left|\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k\right|\leq\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k^4\right)^{\frac{1}{4}}, $$
so, if the RHS tends to zero, so does the LHS.

Answer (score 2):

Use Jensen's inequality, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality on the real-valued function of real numbers
$$
f(x)=x^4\,.
$$

Comment: Does the given hypothesis satisfy the conditions for Jinsent inequality?

Comment: @Aysha: yes. I assume the $a_n$ are real numbers. So, if you use the finite form of Jensen's inequality with the function I suggested, you get $ 0 \leq \left(\frac{a_1+\ldots+a_n}{n}\right)^4 \leq \left(\frac{{a_1}^4+\ldots+{a_n}^4}{n}\right) = 0$

Comment: @Aysha:forgot to add that the zero bounds on either end hold in the limit as $n\rightarrow\infty$, of course, as the question requires.

Comment: That is great and interesting. Thanks

Comment: @AyshaA. : You are welcome. If I have been helpful, please indicate it by voting. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Using CS, you can show, $(\sum_{i} a_i/n)^2\le (\sum_{i}a_i^2/n)$ and similarly $(\sum_{i}a_i^2/n)^2\le (\sum_{i}a_i^4/n)$. So using the given condition the result follows.

Comment: But, will the given hypothesis satisfies the conditions for CS inequality?

Comment: Yes it does if $a_i$ is in some inner product space. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality)